# Show that $0 \longrightarrow \underline{\mathbb{Z}} \longrightarrow \mathscr{O}_X \longrightarrow \mathscr{F} \longrightarrow 0$ is exact

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{C}$ with the classical topology, let $\mathscr{O}_X$ be the sheaf of holomorphic functions and let $\mathscr{F}$ be the presheaf of functions admitting a holomorphic logarithm. Show that $$0 \longrightarrow \underline{\mathbb{Z}} \longrightarrow \mathscr{O}_X \longrightarrow \mathscr{F} \longrightarrow 0$$ is exact where $\underline{\mathbb{Z}} \longrightarrow \mathscr{O}_X$ is given by  the natural inclusion and $\mathscr{O}_X \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}$ is given by $f \mapsto \exp(2\pi if)$. Show also that $\mathscr{F}$ is not a sheaf. (Hint: The problem is that there are functions that don't have a logarithm but locally have a logarithm.)

---

So let $i : \underline{\mathbb{Z}} \to \mathscr{O}_X$ denote the inclusion and $j: \mathscr{O}_X \to \mathscr{F}$. The first question is that how is this $j$ defined? I think they mean that for $U$ open in $X$ we consider $$\begin{align*} j(U): \mathscr{O}_X(U) &\to \mathscr{F}(U) \\\\ j(U)(f) &= \exp(2\pi i f)  \end{align*}$$
but does the rhs of $$j(U)(f) = \exp(2\pi i f)$$ make sense since $f$ is a map from $U$ to some ring?

I think I can only proceed with the problem when I know how this $j$ is supposed to behave as I need to show next that $$\ker(j) = \operatorname{im}(i)$$ to verify exactness.

Comment: $f$ is supposed to be a holomorphic function, so you should know where it is a map to.

Comment: @Thorgott Can you elaborate, it is as if  $\exp(2\pi i f)$ is a composition of the exponential function and $f$?

Comment: You say "f is a map from $U$ to some ring" in the post. I'm saying that you can and should be precise about what the codomain of $f$ is.

Comment: It feels like the codomain should be $\mathbb{R}$. I think I might not be quite clear in what I'm trying to say. What I mean is that the expression $\exp(2\pi i f)$ doesn't feel right. Do we evaluate this like $\exp^{2\pi i f}(u) = \exp^{2\pi i f(u)}$ for $u \in U$? @Thorgott

Comment: Yes, that's how we evaluate it. However, I vehemently disagree about $\mathbb{R}$. Again, what is a holomorphic function?

Comment: Should be $U \to \mathbb{C}$... @Thorgott

Comment: That's right.${}$

Comment: Is it so that in this case $\ker(j) = \ker(j(U))$ for every $U$ open in $X$? If so, then for $f \in \ker(j)$ we have that $$j(U)(f) = \exp(2 \pi i f) = 0.$$ Should this be $0$ or $1$ in our case as $\exp(2 \pi i f) = 0$ is likely always false. @Thorgott

Comment: For the first question, yes. If you feel unsure about this, I suggest reviewing the definition of what an exact sequence of (pre-)sheaves is. For the second question, it should be the neutral element of $\mathcal{F}(U)$. You haven't specified the group operations that make $\mathcal{F}$ into a sheaf of abelian groups, so perhaps you should think about that now.

Comment: Should that have been stated in the problem? If $\mathscr{F}$ is a presheaf of functions admitting a holomorphic log, then for each $U$ we have that $\mathscr{F}(U)$ contains such maps from $U \to \mathbb{C}$. It would be reasonable to assume that the zero map $0$ is the identity if the group operations are given pointwise? @Thorgott

Comment: *Which* pointwise operations?

Comment: So for $s, s' \in \mathscr{F}(U)$ and $u \in U$ we would have $(s+s')(u) = s(u) + s'(u)$? We could probably also have $(s\cdot s')(u) = s(u)s'(u)$. In the first case $0$ should be the identity and in the latter $1$. @Thorgott

Comment: Does $0$ have a logarithm?

Comment: That's a good point. The group operation must be $\cdot$ then. @Thorgott

Comment: Right. Also $j$ should be a homomorphism, so this only works because exponentiation turns addition into multiplication.